# str.find() outputs '-1' when given a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to find the position of the first vowel in a word but it keeps outputting '-1'.  When I change `aLow = word.find(vowel)` to `aLow = word.find("a")`, it works correctly.

```
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']

while True:
    letters = []
    pGWord = ""

    word = raw_input("Type word to 'Pig Latin' it: ")
    low = len(word)

    for vowel in vowels:
        aLow = word.find(vowel)
        if aLow < low:
            low = aLow

    print low
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [br1ckb0t's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30088938/908494]) explains, the problem is that -1 is *smaller* than all indices. So, by correctly returning the lowest index found, you're returning -1 unless *all* of them are found, instead of only if *none* of them are found.

You can fix this easily. Just change this line:

```
if aLow < low:
```

… to:

```
if aLow != -1 and aLow < low:
```

---

There are other ways you could fix this.

---

For example, you could wrap the `find` in a function that pushes `-1` to the end:

```
def darn_minus_one(n):
    return sys.max_int if n==-1 else n

# ...

aLow = darn_minus_one(word.find(vowel))
```

That seems kind of silly, until you realize that it allows you to replace your entire function with:

```
def darn_minus_one(n):
    return len(word) if n==-1 else n
return min((word.find(c) for c in chars), key=darn_minus_one)
```

---

Or you could not use `find` at all, and instead look up each letter in the set of vowels:

```
vowels = set(vowels)
for i, c in enumerate(word):
    if c in vowels:
        return i
return -1
```

Comment: He's doing `for vowel in vowels`, though, which should be providing strings to `find()`.

Comment: I thought since I was iterating through a list it would treat `word.find(vowel)` as `word.find('a')`, then as `word.find('e')`, etc..
Why is that not the case?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Oh, right, he's just expecting the actual value to be somehow `< -1`…

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Fixed and undeleted, since br1ckb0t broke his answer…

Comment: Your solution worked, thank you. So as soon as it didn't find one of the vowels it was set to -1 and lower than any possible position in the word.

Comment: @The_Guy: Exactly. (And sorry for my initial confusion and incorrect answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the issue is stemming from:

```
if aLow < low:
    low = aLow
```

So this means that when `aLow` is `-1`, `low` gets set to `-1`, and then stays there because no indices are less than `-1`.

So no matter what `aLow` is, the output will always be the lowest index, `-1`, unless all the vowels are found, at which point it'll be 0.

Instead, I would avoid the structure you have of starting `low` and `len(word)` and then finding indices less than it. Instead, maybe try something like this:

```
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']

while True:
    letters = []
    pGWord = ""

    word = raw_input("Type word to 'Pig Latin' it: ")
    low = -1

    for vowel in vowels:
        aLow = word.find(vowel)
        if aLow != -1 and aLow < low:
            low = aLow

    if low == -1:
        low = len(word)

    print low
```

Which gives:

```
Type word to 'Pig Latin' it: Stack
>>> 2
```

Comment: It'll always be -1 unless _all_ of the vowels are found, in which case it actually _will_ find the first one…

Comment: Your suggested version will find the _last_ vowel, not the _first_. All you need to do to fix his code is change `aLow < low` to `aLow < low and low != -1` or similar.

Comment: So when it cant find the given letter it outputs -1 and it was not find 'u', the last letter in the list, in all of the test words (because I didn't use 'u' i guess)?

Answer (score -1):

The most simplest answer is to add a `continue`:

```
if aLow < 0:
      continue

if aLow < low:
      low = aLow
```

Reason:

The search needs to `continue` if no match is found without altering the `low` variable.

Comment: No, that doesn't actually fix his problem, and it adds a new one.